GCP Snapshots not named correctly
I have a GCP linux server with multiple external drives that are snapshotted nightly. This issue is the snapshots are mixed. The snapshot for "drive 1" is actually a snapshot of "drive 2" and the snapshot for "drive 2" is actually a snapshot of "drive 1".
The issue seems restricted to a specific project as I have another project where this does not happen.
Anyone seen this before?
